# Smaller screen after installing radeon driver from AMD's site

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I don't know if this is fully Ubuntu related, anyway here's the question:

After I put in AMD Asus 280X and booted the screen size was normal, but after I downloaded and installed AMD's original 14.4 Linux drivers `amd-catalyst-14-4-linux-x86-x86-64.zip`, restarted and booted again, it still was full HD but the screen size is like one inch on every side smaller/compressed. It's like as if you open up an image and scale it to 90% or so, you still see everything but you can see if there were text that the text is not in its original size (kind of blurred). (My LG Flatron IPS234 is connected via HDMI with the graphics card, Ubuntu 14.04 64bit)

Here is an image which shows what I mean (note: the camera made this image extreme blurry, in reality it's just a bit blurry):

[image]

Comment: Did you checked screen resolution in display settings? goto **All settings>Displays** Check screen resolution is set correctly....also check resolution settings in **ati catalyst**

Comment: Under the Desplays settings it says it is a "Goldstar Company Ltd 23"" and the shown resolution there is "1920 x 1080", which is correct, but the display name is not correct. 

Under catalyst it shows "1. IPS234" and "1920 x 1080", which is correct.

Comment: chcek this http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=330331

Comment: 1. Catalyst Control Center
2. Graphics
3. Desktops and Displays
4. Right click the display that has the incorrect displayed area. There will be two if there is another device added (like a tv).
5. Configure
6. Scaling Options
7. Slide the arrow to the right "Overscan to 0%".

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the Scaling Options :\ https://i.imgur.com/rpzZUFf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting Catalyst Control Center *Scaling Options* to  'Overscan  0%' and see..

[image]

Comment: can you post what window you see.. on opening catalyst.. it should be under displays..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the Scaling Options :\ https://i.imgur.com/rpzZUFf.png

Comment: are you are opening catalyst control center in administrative mode? If not try again in administrative mode and see scaling options are coming?

Comment: else see and try this link http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2064230

Comment: I guess yes `sudo amdcccle`. Also opening from the menu "... (Administrative)" is the same.

Comment: yes with passwrd if you r opening then correcet

Comment: ubuntuforums user writes "launch the ATI Catalyst Control Config program (in the settings menu or aticonfig from command prompt) and:

Display Manager -> [select your screen] -> "Adjustments" tab -> set 'scaling options' overscan to 0% " but where is it..if I launch aticonfig/amdconfig it is just a commandline program

Comment: also try set graphics processor for scaling in here... https://i.imgur.com/rpzZUFf.png

Comment: Did already try

Comment: hope this work.... http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1409508.html says  sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0

Comment: I got it!:
**1.** from amdconfig I got the display types 
"The DISPLAYTYPE in options can be one of the following strings:
        crt1,  lvds,   tv,   cv,   tmds1, crt2,
        tmds2, tmds2i, dfp3, dfp4, dfp5,  dfp6 ."
**2.** Then I used the script from ubuntuforums ?t=2064230 and tried the types until the type **dfp5** worked :)

It's basically these four lines
aticonfig --set-dispattrib=$DISPLAY_TYPE,positionX:0
aticonfig --set-dispattrib=$DISPLAY_TYPE,positionY:0
aticonfig --set-dispattrib=$DISPLAY_TYPE,sizeX:$WIDTH
aticonfig --set-dispattrib=$DISPLAY_TYPE,sizeY:$HEIGHT

Answer (score 1):

Use this command, it should work:

```
sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0
```

I have a how-to on my blog, www.ligti.se.

Reference : [BinaryDriverHowto/AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#HDTV_underscan)

Comment: Which post on your blog is the howto that contains that code/command? Searching the ligti.se domain for it with Google doesn't turn up anything. Also, you may want to edit this answer to explain what that command is doing.